# rollup with rexport interfaces and enums as typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rollup

I have self created library (eg: library-A) which includes a list of interfaces, enums and constants and published as a tar

I have also created another react library (eg: library-B) which consume (library-A) and use rollup to build a dist folder.

However, when I install this react library (library-B) in my main project (project-A), I cannot seem to access the interfaces, enums and constants from (library-A). Are there any ways I can use the interfaces, enums and constants from (library-A) which are re-exported by (library-B)

library-A

```
export interface PERSON {
   name: string;
   age: number;
}

export enum GENDER {
   male= 'male',
   female= 'female'
}
```

library-B -> rollup.config.js

```
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import peerDepsExternal from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2';
import packageJson from './package.json';

const config = {
  input: 'src/index.ts',
  output: [
    {
      file: packageJson.main,
      format: 'cjs',
      sourcemap: true,
    },
    {
      file: packageJson.module,
      format: 'esm',
      sourcemap: true,
    },
  ],
  plugins: [
    peerDepsExternal(),
    resolve(),
    commonjs(),
    typescript({
      tsconfig: 'tsconfig-rollup.json',
    }),
    postcss(),
  ],
};

export default config;
```

library-B -> index.ts

```
export { GENDER } from 'library-A'; // enum
export type { PERSON, CLASSES } from 'library-A'; // interfaces
```

project-A -> home.ts

```
import { GENDER } from "library-B" 

GENDER.male // this is not found
```

Comment: Add library-A codes

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you want to access something from lib-A in lib-B and vice versa. I am not sure if this is possible but it appears to me as not a good idea.

I would suggest, if you want to share constants and interfaces in two projects, put them into lib-C and include this lib-C in lib-A and in lib-B.

Comment: I think the issue is rollup doesn't seem to recognize the types from B while compiling A